How to show the limit of a series of convolutions exist?
Suppose $\rho:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ is an even, smooth test function, compactly supported in the ball of radius $1$. Define $\rho^{(n)}(x):=2^{nd}\rho(2^nx),$ and
$$\rho^{(n,m)}:=\rho^{(n)}\ast \rho^{(n+1)}\cdots\rho^{(m)},\quad \quad (*)$$
where $\ast$ stands for convolution.
We also set $\varphi^{(n)}:=\lim_{m\to \infty}\rho^{(n,m)},$ so that in particular, $\varphi^{(n)}=\rho^{(n)}\ast\varphi^{(n+1)}.$ My first question is, how to show $\varphi^{(n)}$ exists?

My attempts: I was trying to use the following theorem:
Theorem(Paley-Wiener) A test function supported on a closed ball at the origin on $\mathbb{R}$ has Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ extending to an entire function on $\mathbb{C},$ with
$$|\hat{f}(z)|\ll_N (1+|z|)^{-N}e^{r|y|}\quad\quad (\text{for } z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C}\text{ and every }\mathbb{N}).$$
Then the Fourier transform of the RHS of $(*)$ gives
$$\hat{\rho}^{(n,m)}(\xi)=\hat{\rho}^{(n)}(\xi)\hat{\rho}^{(n+1)}(\xi)\cdots \hat{\rho}^{(m)}(\xi),$$
with each of the $\hat{\rho}^{(i)}\leq 1$ for $n\leq i \leq m.$ Letting $m\to \infty,$ we get $\lim_{m\to \infty} \hat{\rho}^{(n,m)}(\xi)=0,$ so that $\hat{\varphi}^{(n)}$ exists, as well as $\varphi^{(n)}.$ Is this correct?

My second question is, is it possible to show that $\varphi^{(n)}(x)=\frac{1}{2^{nd}}\psi^{(n)}(\frac{x}{2^n}),$ for some test function $\psi^{(n)}$ on $\mathbb{R}^d,$ for each $n$? For this one I currently have no idea, and thank you very much in advance for any hints and solutions!
